# jQuery mouseleave firing multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I have an svg container with multiple child  elements that I attached a jQuery event handler to (.mouseleave). It works, but every time it gets fired, the following execution it get fired multiple times... so, the first time mouseleave gets triggered, it fires once as expected, but the second time it fired twice, the third time three times, and so on. I have no idea what's causing this and wasn't able to find anything by googling. Here's a screenshot and the code:

[image][image]

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: It's very likely that you're attaching additional event listeners with every onmouseleave. I recommend detaching any previous listeners, for instance, whenever you mouseover the SVG element, or just before the mouseleave event listener declaration.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear. The point of asking the question was to see if anyone had encountered this issue before and would be able to point out a simple mistake I was making or inform me that there is a bug with the function that's known but obscure and not easily found via google. If I took the time to produce the "shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem" I probably would have solved it on my own (which I might have to do), but I'd obviously rather take a faster route if possible.

Comment: It was clear to me! Post doesn't deserve downvotes...except for the lack of copyable code ;)

Comment: Not a real answer but while @JonathanBrooks, answer will indeed solve your problem, your code seems strange.  You create a jquery "mouseleave" event handler on a d3 "mouseout".  It looks like you do this to create a closure to leave the d3 "this" in scope but then don't use it.  So, 1.) why the strange closure wrapping?  2.), why are you dynamically creating the event handlers at all? And 3.), why mix jquery and d3?

Comment: I wrap snippets of code in self-executing functions for a number of reasons; first and foremost is that in my IDE (brackets, though almost any development environment should have this feature by now) I can collapse the code to get it out of my way then pop it open only when I need it. I name the function to describe what it's doing and preface it with an underscore to differentiate it from anything else. This makes it extremely easy to navigate my code as I can have open only the code that I'm currently working on, and easily see at a glance what's going on elsewhere.

Comment: There are more reasons why it's useful but too much to post here

Comment: Oh and I'm mixing d3 and jQuery because the d3 "mouseleave" (really just the default javascript event) doesn't do what I need it to do so I had to improvise.

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure your problem arises due to multiple attachments of event listeners to your dom elements. Try adding this before the `$('#svgArcs').mouseleave(function(e){` line:

```
$('#svgArcs').off('mouseleave')
```

That should fix it.

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. Thanks! Didn't know you could attach the same event multiple times.

Comment: Excellent, glad to help! Don't forget to accept the answer when you can :)